# Is there a way to indicate both React JSX and ECMAScript 6 files in the same project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I have server side node files for which WebStorm gives warnings if I set the JavaScript language version is set to `React JSX` and then I have client side files with JSX that will have warnings if it is set to `ECMAScript 6`.

Is there a way to indicate both types of files in the same project? One option is to split it into multiple projects but I'd prefer to avoid that.

[image]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default webstorm sets `*.es6` to ECMAScript.
You could also specify a custom file type by following the guide [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)

[image]